# How can I store a file path in Mysql database using django?

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, django

I need to store a file path in db using django via ajax form submission .

Here is my view:

```html
def dashboard(request):
    container=[]
    DIR = os.path.realpath("/home/user/Desktop/Demo")
    WAY = os.listdir(DIR)
    for file in WAY:
        if file.endswith('.mp4'):
            file_name = file
            FDIR=os.path.join(DIR, file)
            container.append(FDIR)
            
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'container': container})
```

```
def new_scheduler(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        f_name = request.POST.get('file')
        dateAndTime = request.POST.get('dateAndTime')
    Scheduled_data = schedulesdb.objects.create(
            f_name = file,
            dateAndTime = dateAndTime,  
        )
    Scheduled_data.save()
    return HttpResponse ('done')
```

It save in database like `<type 'file'>` .

Here is my model.py:

```
class schedulesdb(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateAndTime = models.DateTimeField(['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'],null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=2)
    def __unicode__(self):              #  on Python 2
        return self.f_name
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're saying the database field contains the string "<type 'file'>"?

Comment: yes ! in f_name column it stores only  <type 'file'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it's not 100% clear whether you're intending to handle file uploads from the client, or simply store strings that happen to be a file path (potentially for locating a file on some remote filesystem).

**1. File uploads**

Consider using the [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) model field type rather than the CharField.

The Django documentation has a solid explanation and examples of how to do simple [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/).

**2. Obtaining the actual POST data value for the f_name field**

Your code sample is storing "", because you're assigning 'file' (which is a builtin type) rather than the `f_name` variable that you previously declared. Like this:

```
def new_scheduler(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    f_name = request.POST.get('file')
    dateAndTime = request.POST.get('dateAndTime')
Scheduled_data = schedulesdb.objects.create(
        f_name = f_name, # Note the use of f_name instead of file
        dateAndTime = dateAndTime,  
    )
Scheduled_data.save()
return HttpResponse ('done')
```

Comment: I only want to save my local directory's file path into database , I tried doing this , It did not work for me .

Comment: Was there a change in the value that's being stored in the DB? If you open python in the shell, and type 'file', the shell will print the string representation of the built in File class. So it's clear that the field is being assigned the "File" object and not the proper POST data. Another possibility is that request.POST.get('file') is causing problems. Perhaps try giving the POST data field a different name that doesn't clash.

Comment: Thanks that was fine !

Answer (score 0):

I haven't even used ajax, but I stored file path in mysql and stored file in media folder in django
Here's my views.py:

```
    from CRUDoperation.models import EmpModel
    def upload(request):
    

        if request.method == 'POST':
                saverecord=EmpModel()
                myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
                uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
                saverecord.file=uploaded_file_url
        return render(request,'upload.html')


models.py file

class EmpModel(models.Model):
        file=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    class Meta:
        db_table="employee"

settings.py file

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

my html code:
{% load static %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```